# What to consider when choosing a location for a LED strip power supply?

Tags: led, power-supply

I'm renovating a bit again and in one place I want to provide lighting via a LED strip mounted at the ceiling corner. That will be 3m of LED strips, and I'd like the place to be well lit, so I'm aiming for 1000lm/m or above. That then equates to slightly less than 15W/m or 45W altogether. The nearest power supply that I see is 60W. I want to tuck this power supply out of sight - and I have a place for that, but it is also at a ceiling corner - and will likely be covered with other stuff (it's a storage area), so I'm a bit worried about heat buildup.

Another worry I have is that very close to that place I intend to put my wifi router. How electromagnetically noisy are these power supplies? Is it likely to interfere with my wifi signal and should I make faraday cage to put around it? Or is that overthinking it?

So, to recap:

- Do I need to worry about the LED strip power supply overheating?
- Do I need to worry about EM interference with my nearby Wifi router?

Comment: These are two very different questions (even though they both relate to your current project) and should be asked separately.

Comment: AFAIK the power supply will only provide what the lights draw.  If you provide a 1000W PS, your lights will still only draw 45W, and the PS will only provide 45W.  If you provide *less* than 45W your lights may be dim, or not work at all.